# concave and strictly increasing function without differentiable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, convex-analysis

If a function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous, concave, and strictly increasing (not necessary need $g$ is differentiable), then for every $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, how to prove that $\left| g (a + c) - g (b + c) \right|  \leq \left| g (a ) - g(b) \right| $ is valid?

Actually, I proved this statement by using the differentiation of $g$. However, in this statement, we don't know whether $g$ is differentiable, so is there anyone could prove this statement without using the differentiation of $g$?

Does right-differentiation of $g$ reach the purpose?

Anyway, I attached my orignal proof. Hopefully it could be helpful to you.

Proof:
Without loss of generality, we assume $a \leq b$. Since $g$ is increasing, $ g(a) \leq g(b)$. To prove above inequality will be equivalent to show that $g(b+c) - g(b) \leq  g(a+c) - g(a)$.

To this end, we set a function $f(x) := g(x + c) - g(x)$, for all $ c$ in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Taking the derivative of $f$ w.r.t $x$, we get $f'(x) = g '(x + c) - g '(x)$. Because $g$ is concave, its first-order derivative is non-increasing, namely, $ g '(x + c) \leq g '(x) $, and thus, $f'(x)  \leq 0$ ($f$ is decreasing).

So, $a \leq b$ implies $ f(a) \geq f(b)$, that is, $ g(a+c) - g(a) \geq g(b+c) - g(b) $. The stated property follows.

Comment: A concave function is absolutely continuous. Hence, it is almost everywhere differentiable and the fundamental theorem of calculus applies. This should salvage your proof.

Comment: @gerw Thank you very much. As you said, $g$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $x \in \mathbb{R}$. However, from my proof, it seems like we need $g$ has a derivative $g'$ everywhere. And I think in this case, differentiable almost everywhere is quite different with differentiable everywhere. If so, how to improve my proof?

Comment: I think you get $f'(x) \le 0$ for a.e. $x$ and this gives $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks, @gerw. May I ask you one more question? Because in my question, function $g$ is mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$. Since $g$ is concave, it is absolutely continuous on any closed subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$. In order to get $g$ has a derivative for a.e. $x$ on $\mathbb{R}$, if I want to apply the fundamental theorem of Lebesuge integral calculus, according to the theorem, $g$ should be defined on a closed (compact) interval. So, how could I extend the domain of $g$ to $(- \infty, +\infty)$ or $ [ 0, + \infty)$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It suffices to work on $[a, b+c]$.

Comment: You're right, @gerw. Thanks so much again!!